# One Vuejs Pinia store with namespacing actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Can pinia actions be divided into two namespaces, such that access happens over property n1 and n2 such that:

```
// current
store.n1a('hi')
store.n2b()
// wanted
store.n1.a('hi')
store.n2.b()

// ugly workaround:
store.namespace1().a('hi')
// store would look like
  actions: {
    namespace1() {
      return {
        a(msg) {
          console.log(msg);
        }, 
      };
     ....
    },
  },
```

It helps with clean f() naming a lot. bath.paint() and kitchen.paint() instead of bathPaint() etc. Similar: https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#expose

Comment: I don't really understand your question. But pinia is namespaced by design. Each store is a `module/namespace` and isolate from others. You can define as many stores as you want

Comment: you miss the Q; i simply try to organize the actions into namespaces operating all on one little state (thus stored in one place). Pinias approach seems to be to have two store1/2.js and import the state.js into each  to split getters. i dont want two stores.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to share and what you do not want to share between the two 'namespaces', but it sounds like you just want to write a wrapper. Either when creating a module, or when accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Pinia doesn't need namespace.

You can access another store just by importing.

[Link](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html#accessing-other-stores-getters)

My advice will be to create two separate stores and access them as you want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).